# VS 2010 cannot see build controller from TFS2012

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfsbuild

I have Team Foundation Server 2012 Express installed to be used with Visual Studio 2010.
I have installed SP1 and can view and use the Team Project in Visual Studio 2010.

I have setup build controllers in TFS but I cannot see them in VS2010.  When I click on the 'New Build Definition' option I get the error message:

> Creating a build defintion requires a build controller be definied for
>   this team project collection.  There may not be any controllers
>   configured or you may not have the permissions to view them.  Contract
>   your Team Foundation Server administrator

I have added my name to every build group I can see in the Team Foundation Express Admin Console so I think it is unlikely (although not impossible) that it is a rights issue.

Has anyone else come across this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it - the build controller was not in the correct workspace!